# How to get a unique id with MongoDB in String Boot

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I am currently trying to create my first backend service. Currently I am struggeling with creating a unique id for every user. I saw that with many MySQL databases you can create a unique id by using annotations in the java code. That's what I currently have. Does anybody know what I have to change to get unique ids?

```
import lombok.*;
import me.kifo.ucactivitymanager.utils.Faction;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;

@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Document(collection = "users")
public class AppUser implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private AppUserRole appUserRole;
    private Boolean locked;
    private Boolean enabled;
    private Faction faction;

    public AppUser(String name, String email, String password, AppUserRole appUserRole, Boolean locked, Boolean enabled, Faction faction) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.appUserRole = appUserRole;
        this.locked = locked;
        this.enabled = enabled;
        this.faction = faction;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        SimpleGrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(appUserRole.name());
        return Collections.singletonList(authority);
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return !locked;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }
}
```

Comment: change private Long id to String id. rest remains the same.

Comment: I will leave the exercise is to why you should change into String. but its something related to ObjectId. Let me know if this worked. I post this as an answer.

Comment: To add to @Suchandra's comments, if you set the type of your `Id` field to either `java.lang.String` or `org.bson.types.ObjectId`, then this will be populated with a unique value by Mongo.